# How to both center a <div> and have it use fixed positioning?

Tags: html, css, width, margin, fixed

I have a div with some text on my page, and I want it to be at the bottom. I did this using **fixed positioning**:

```
div#popup{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
```

But I also want it to be centered. I tried giving it a width of 40% and auto margins, but that doesn't work (it doesn't work with the combination of the above code) :

```
 div#popup{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin- right: auto;
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know width of div you can use negative margin-left for horizontal position (which equals half of width).

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: -20%;
    background: blue;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/igoradamenko/9mqsd6xa/)

If you don't know width, just use wrapper and inline-blocks:

HTML:

```
<section>
    <div>la-la-la</div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 100%;

    text-align: center;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/igoradamenko/o1z9cah9/)

Answer (score 1):

I encourage You to check two nice tutorials (quick read):

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning
http://learnlayout.com/position.html

I think You need to describe position like this:

```
div#popup{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should never use fixed positioning to get your footer to stick to the bottom. To get the footer to stick to the bottom of the screen, set all your divs to relative, then add an extra div the same height as the footer (set a height for your footer) between the content and the footer. Then put a margin of negative that height on your content div. Works perfectly.

To centre it, use width auto and margin left and right auto or just use text-align center

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qekawewuxu/edit?html,css,output an example of using the extra div